# Django filter related field using through model's custom manager

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models and a custom manager to filter out non active items:

```py
class List(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField("Item", through="ListItem")

class ListItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ListItemManager, self).get_queryset().filter(item__is_active=True)

class ListItem(OrderedModel):
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item")

    objects = ListItemManager()
```

Why does this not work as I would expect?

```py
active_list_items = List.objects.first().items # Contains items with `is_active=False` :(
```

I would like to have a default filter on the many-to-many relationship. What is the correct way to filter out non active items through my through model?

Comment: You have overridden the manager of `ListItem` model, but you are querying the `List` model

Comment: So where does the `through` come to play?

Comment: [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a default filter on the many-to-many relationship.